# How to write characteristic fast and stable for BLE in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing for BLE in Android. The Android can send data to BLE device by `Gatt.writeCharacteristic`.

But When I write consecutive **Characteristic** to BLE device (5 times in 1 Second) , I will get `GATT_DISCONNECTED` and it return `null` when I try to `getService` and `GetCharacteristic`.

I have seen some **BLE LED product** in market. It use a color picker in Android like the following picture:

[image]

When user change the color fast on the color picker , the **BLE LED** also change the color immediately.

How to write characteristic fast and stable for BLE in Android like the BLE LED product in market ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `gatt.writeCharacteristic` you need to do 2 things:

1. You need to queue up the gatt read and write requests so that when you make a read or write request, you must wait for the corresponding callback in BluetoothGattCallback before requesting the next read or write. This is an Android BluetoothGatt behavior that is not well documented.
2. Somewhat related to 1. above, you should check the boolean return value of the gatt read and write requests.  If it does not return true, then your request failed. This occurs when some other gatt operation is in still in progress at the time you make the next request.

I have found that the best way to read (or write) BLE characteristics fast is to make the request, wait for the callback and make the next request from the callback. If there is a faster or more reliable way, I am unaware of it.

Comment: if i have many operations to do, how can i synchronize these operations ?? i mean waiting the callback of one operation to do the next

Comment: I have an object that represents my ble device. Its api looks like:
  object.readX, obj.writeY, obj.addListener(l).  Inside it implements a command queue (a java.util.Queue) where each readX or writeY (gatt operation) is queued. The queue get serviced upon the ble callbacks (and a timeout incase the callback never occurs. thats the basic idea

Comment: I try to use ArrayDeque to implement it. After the write/read callback has feedback , requesting the next read or write.  But the speed is too slow...

Comment: You are the mother! / Είσαι η μάνα!

Comment: You saved my life.